# Contact form issues on HTML5 theme

Tags: php, html, contact-form

Forgive me, as this probably has an extremely simple solution and I'm just very inexperienced.

I am using the Massive HTML5 theme and cannot get my contact form to work. I thought I followed the directions, but still nothing happens when I click SUBMIT.

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<form method="post" action="contact-us.php" id="form" role="form" class="contact-comments">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 ">
      <div class="form-group">
        <!-- Name -->
        <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class=" form-control" placeholder="Name *" maxlength="100" required="">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <!-- Email -->
        <input type="email" name="email" id="email" class=" form-control" placeholder="Email *" maxlength="100" required="">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <!-- phone -->
        <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" class=" form-control" placeholder="Phone" maxlength="100">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 form-group">
      <div class="form-group">
        <!-- Comment -->
        <textarea name="text" id="text" class="cmnt-text form-control" placeholder="Comment" maxlength="400"></textarea>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group full-width">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-small btn-dark-solid ">
          Send Message
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

```php
<?php
// Note: filter_var() requires PHP >= 5.2.0
if ( isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['subject']) && isset($_POST['comments']) && filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) ) {

    // detect & prevent header injections
    $mailTest = "/(content-type|bcc:|cc:|to:)/i";
    foreach ( $_POST as $key => $val ) {
        if ( preg_match( $mailTest, $val ) ) {
            exit;
        }
    }

    $headers = 'From: ' . $_POST["name"] . '<' . $_POST["email"] . '>' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: ' . $_POST["email"] . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

    $success = mail( "myemail@mail.com", $_POST['subject'], $_POST['comments'], $headers );
    //  Replace with your email

    if ($success) {
        ?>
        <div style="color:#3c763d;padding:30px;text-align:center">
            <strong>Success!</strong> Message has been sent successfully.
        </div>
        <?php
    }
}
```

Of course, I changed myemail@mail.com to my address.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: What is your URL?

Answer (score 0):

> mail() function  Returns TRUE if the mail was successfully accepted for delivery, FALSE otherwise.
>
> It is important to note that just because the mail was accepted for delivery, it does NOT mean the mail will actually reach the intended destination.

please refer [Documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) .

you can also other php library  to send mail like phpmailer.

Answer (score 0):

```
 if ( isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['email']) && filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
```

Remove && isset($_POST['subject']) && isset($_POST['comments']) from your if condition as their are no inputs with names subject and comments in your HTML form.

Answer (score 0):

If you're on Windows then use [XAMPP](https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html), if on Mac use [MAMP](https://www.mamp.info/en/).

PHP contact form will not work if don't have any server side connection. I had the similar problem as you have now. For more information please check my post [Configuration issue with PHP contact form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36999361/configuration-issue-with-php-contact-form).

Comment: I have been uploading it to my host so this isn't the problem, correct?

Comment: @RebeccaWalsh But you still might want to test if the code you have works locally, rather than uploading it straight to the host. With XAMPP or MAMP you make your computer think that he's a host. Btw, is the path to your contact-us.php correct?